# How to find a table in sql server if only the partial table name is known

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a sql server database which contains 7000 `tables` and every table ends with a `date`. I need to find out all the `tables` of a particular `date`.

I have the table names as follows:

```
HouseKeeping_Stage1_12_6_14,
HouseKeeping_Stage1_13_6_14,
HouseKeeping_Stage1_14_6_14,
HouseKeeping_Stage2_12_6_14,
HouseKeeping_Stage2_13_6_14
```

I want to find out all the records which are associated with the `date 12_6_14`.

Please let me know how to write the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SSMS Object Explorer, right-click on the Tables node and select Filter-->Filter Settings.  The list will be filtered accordingly.

Alternatively, you can query the catalog or INFORMATION_SCHEMA views:

```
SELECT 
      OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) AS schema_name
    , name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '%[_]13[_]6[_]14%';

SELECT 
      TABLE_SCHEMA
    , TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%[_]13[_]6[_]14%';
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
where table_name like '%12_6_14%'
```

Here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/304bd/1/0